# Highlight Slick grid row based on the Column Value

Tags: conditional-statements, slickgrid, highlighting

I am using slick grid to show JSON data. [image]

On external button click i want highlight specific row based on  column values.

**Such as highlight row which have  cost=75 and venue_id =87  and Impression=268**

Comment: please post what have you tried....and any issue faced...

Answer (score 0):

Got solution :

```
 dataView.getItemMetadata = function (row) {

                    var item = dataView.getItem(row);


                    if (item["" + columnName+ ""] == colValue)
                     {
                        return { cssClasses: 'highlight' };

                    }
                    return null;

                }
  grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, myColList, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other suggested option seems to be have heavy load on my system, as my system have thousand of records and a particular row have to highlighted and suggested solution kind of refreshes the whole table. For some reasons it is not working for me.

I got around this by using Slickgrid's flashCell. Even no need of `getItemMetadata()`

```
            var rowId=dataView.getRowById(idvalue);//id of the row to be highlighted, as slickgrid enforced an id field
            grid.scrollRowToTop(rowId);//makes the row visible
            grid.getColumns().forEach(function(col){//get all the columns
            grid.flashCell(rowId, grid.getColumnIndex(col.id));//flash it
            })
```

Hope this helps to coming to this page for the answer.